# Check if a string is an English word?

Tags: java

I've looked around to find a way to see if a string is a valid english word but all the solutions I find involves me using a predefined list of words. I just want the string to be compared against a local dictionary. Is there a way to do this?

Right now my code takes in a string and is sent to this method

```
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/usr/local/share/dict"));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if ( str.contains( word )) {
             return true;
        } else {
             return false;
        }
    }
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Is a local dictionary not a predefined list of words? Or have I misunderstood what you mean?

Comment: You could also look for a good API and use a Java URL to make an API call and retrieve the response. Based on some quick google-fu, I found http://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php

Comment: There is no single canonical list of valid english words. Witness the need for every word processor in the world to have an "add word to dictionary" feature.

Answer (score 4):

[Wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) has a Java API you can use; if you really want a local hashmap/hashset then you can construct one out of Wordnet's database.

Comment: Wordnet doesn't include prepositions or "the"